# Question about positive recurrence of a Birth and death chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains

Q) Let $X_n$ be a random walk on $\{0,1,\cdots\}$ s.t. $p(i,i+1)=p_i, p(i,i-1)=1-p_i=q_i$. $p(0,0)=1-p_0$. Show that $X_n$ is positive recurrent if and only if:

$$\sum_i \prod_{0<j\leq i} \frac{p(j-1)}{q(j)} < \infty$$

Durrett has a claim saying that the chain is recurrent if and only if:

$$\sum_i \prod_{0<j\leq i} \frac{q(j)}{p(j)} = \infty$$

the proof of which I understand but may I know how to go from recurrence to showing positive recurrence?

Comment: The chain has an invariant measure $\nu$ satisfying $\nu=\nu P$ where $P$ is the transition matrix for $\{X_n\}$ if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \nu(k)<\infty$, where $\nu(k) = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{p_j}{q_{j+1}}$. In this situation the chain is clearly positive recurrent, as it has a (unique) stationary distribution $\pi=\frac1{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \nu(k)} \nu$.